# Pass non rfc compliant urls to Fastapi from Uvicorn

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

If the incoming urls are non RFC compliant (eg, urls like "http://urls with spaces" or urls with un encoded unicode characters), Uvicorn returns default 400 error and response

We want the Uvicorn pass that url to Fastapi and let Fastapi take appropriate action. How to achieve this. At the very least we want to be able to send a formatted respons in case of errors.

We are migrating our old API to FastAPI and compatibility is essential, legacy system doesn't reject these inputs. Also our clients are constrained devices which cannot be upgraded

We couldn't find anything in the documentation

Comment: Do you have an example with a curl request that shows the issue? Are you running `uvicorn` directly (and with what settings), or are you using gunicorn with a uvicorn worker? (and which one?) Did you install `uvicorn` or `uvicorn[standard]` (which pulls some different dependencies)?